# indesign sdk - sample plugin not working

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm trying to develop a new plugin for InDesign. But for now I'm taking a look at some samples that comes with the SDK. The fact is that I can't get these plugins to work on InDesign(SnippetRunner for example). I compile then, get a build successful message and move it to the plugin's InDesign directory, as well as it's resource directory. They load correctly (cause I get not message error during start up). But the plug-in's tab do not show up. It's like there isn't any plugins in there.

What could be happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I just figured it out. You don't find the SnippetRunner under the "Plug-Ins" in the menu bar on top but you find it under "Window" -> "SnippetRunner".

[image: SnippetRunner Adobe InDesign CC]